# Retrieving file bad descriptor and unpack requires a bytes object of length error python socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, struct, opencv3.0

I am sending frames from server to the client, I am retrieving error. Would anyone please help me with this?

```
import socket, cv2, pickle, struct
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_ip = 'ip' 
port = 8080
client_socket.connect((host_ip, port)) 
data = b""
payload_size = struct.calcsize("Q")
while True:
   while len(data) < payload_size:
       packet = client_socket.recv(4 * 1024)
       if not packet: break
       data += packet
   packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
   data = data[payload_size:]
   msg_size = struct.unpack("Q", packed_msg_size)[0]
   while len(data) < msg_size:
       data += client_socket.recv(4 * 1024)
   frame_data = data[:msg_size]
   data = data[msg_size:]
   frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)
client_socket.close()
```

//////

```
import socket, cv2, pickle, struct
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_name = socket.gethostname()
host_ip = 'ip'
port = 8080
socket_address = (host_ip, port)
server_socket.bind(socket_address)
server_socket.listen(5)
print("LISTENING AT:", socket_address)
while True:
   client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
   print('GOT CONNECTION FROM:', addr)
   if client_socket:
       vid = cv2.VideoCapture("C:/Users/test.mp4")
       while (vid.isOpened()):
           img, frame = vid.read()
           a = pickle.dumps(frame)
           message = struct.pack("Q", len(a)) + a
           client_socket.sendall(message)
           client_socket.close()
```

Error

```
File "client_video.py", line 17, in <module> msg_size = struct.unpack("Q", packed_msg_size)[0] struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 8
File "server.py", line 29, in <module> client_socket.sendall(message) OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Thanks, help is highly appreciated

Comment: For the second error, you're closing `client_socket` at the bottom of the loop, but then you try to use the closed socket again on the next iteration. You probably don't want to close it in the loop.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, thank you so much you saved my day. It's working perfectly fine now. Once again really thankful to you